# Android SSL error: certificate not trusted

Tags: java, android, https

In the app I'm working on, I have to make an HTTPS connection to my web server which uses self signed certificate. I was getting certificate not trusted errors and after consulting SO, I found this blog posting: http://blog.antoine.li/index.php/2010/10/android-trusting-ssl-certificates/

I created a JKS keystore for my tomcat running on my local machine using Keytool with following command

```
 keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore keystore.jks -storepass password -validity 360 -keysize 2048
```

And i extracted certificate from that JKS keystore in DER Encoded format using a open source tool called [portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/)

And then i created a new BKS KeyStore with the above certificate using the same portecle tool as android has built support for Bouncy Castle provider.

Now if i make a http post as shown in the first URL, I am getting the following exception in the logcat.

```
WARN/System.err(498): javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificate
WARN/System.err(498):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:371)
WARN/System.err(498):     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:92)
WARN/System.err(498):     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:381)
WARN/System.err(498):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:164)
WARN/System.err(498):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
WARN/System.err(498):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
WARN/System.err(498):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:348)
WARN/System.err(498):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
WARN/System.err(498):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
WARN/System.err(498):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
WARN/System.err(498):     at com.portal.activity.Registration$ProgressThread.run(Registration.java:324)
WARN/System.err(498): Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trust anchors set is empty
WARN/System.err(498):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:151)
WARN/System.err(498):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:366)
WARN/System.err(498):     ... 10 more
WARN/System.err(498): Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trust anchors set is empty
WARN/System.err(498):     at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.checkTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:611)
WARN/System.err(498):     at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.<init>(PKIXParameters.java:86)
WARN/System.err(498):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.<init>(TrustManagerImpl.java:82)
WARN/System.err(498):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.engineGetTrustManagers(TrustManagerFactoryImpl.java:132)
WARN/System.err(498):     at javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(TrustManagerFactory.java:226)
WARN/System.err(498):     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createTrustManagers(SSLSocketFactory.java:263)
WARN/System.err(498):     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.<init>(SSLSocketFactory.java:190)
WARN/System.err(498):     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.<init>(SSLSocketFactory.java:216)
WARN/System.err(498):     at com.portal.httpclient.MyHttpClient.newSslSocketFactory(MyHttpClient.java:51)
WARN/System.err(498):     at com.portal.httpclient.MyHttpClient.createClientConnectionManager(MyHttpClient.java:31)
WARN/System.err(498):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.getConnectionManager(AbstractHttpClient.java:221)
WARN/System.err(498):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:539)
WARN/System.err(498):     ... 3 more
```

My HttpClient is same as in the first URL except that ports for http and https are changed to 8080 and 8443 instead of 80 and 443 respectively.

Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https

Comment: @Divyesh-Thanks for the response.I don't want to accept all certificates.I want to build my own trusted store so that i can accept certificates from that server only.I want it the similar way which is specified in the first URL of my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stopped using portecle and did everything using commandline

i am using just keytool for doing everything as shown in the URL of my question.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can find instructions for using custom truststores with Android here http://blog.crazybob.org/2010/02/android-trusting-ssl-certificates.html

Briefly:

- Get the public cert for the server
- Create a BKS truststore with that certificate
- Create and use a custom HttpClient for your post

Sounds like you've done the top two but not the bottom step.

Also, did Portecle use the correct flags? You need the `trustcacerts` flag when creating the BKS store or it won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I did all the three steps.I didn't post the third step here.I will have to check on the trustcacerts flag in portecle.

Comment: I didn't find any flag for setting in portecle.Can you download from the URL i mentioned and check out

Comment: @Sreeram I can't see a specific option, though I'd guess you should use the 'Import Trusted Certificate' item. As a troubleshooting step, I recommend recreating your truststore using the command line (as per the link I provided).

Comment: I found out the flag. I will try with setting it and let you know